how to create www-data:www-data
www-data is in /etc/group but not /etc/passwd. When I try to create a www-data user with
sudo adduser www-data

I get this message:
adduser: The group `www-data' already exists

This message doesn't make any sense. When I run
apache2ctl configtest

I get
chown: invalid user: 'www-data'

which also doesn't make sense.
There is nothing in the apache error.log file.
The apache envars file specifies that the user and group must be www-data:www-data, but Ubuntu will not let me make a user named www-data. I have tried different ways to do this, such as using the system Options dialog, useradd, usermod, etc., with no luck.
Apache2 will not run without www-data:www-data.
Any help, please.

As confusing as it might seem, you should use useradd instead of adduser
useradd -g www-data --shell=/usr/sbin/nologin www-data

This command will create an user named www-data and add it to the existing group named www-data.
The adduser command is just a helper that will call useradd and a few more commands. Furthermore useradd won't create a /home/www-data folder, which would be unwanted.
EDIT : adding the --shell prevents from directly logging in as www-data, as it must remain a system account.

Thank you! That worked! I had tried a couple of permutations of useradd, but none worked. I (mistakenly) thought I would have to first create a user, www-data, which Ubuntu would not allow. Your method creates the user and adds to the group in one step. I don't understand what the --shell is all about, but my problem is solved. I have closed the question.
